# Conflict between jquery lightbox and flash/html5 video - only in chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, html5-video, lightbox, flash-video

I have a wordpress ng gallery template: http://bit.ly/LTJ9ee, the lightbox of which behaves oddly in chrome when a video is embedded on the same page. The problems only occur when:

- Using chrome (v23). Tested on all other major browsers (windows 7) with no problems.
- If the page is too big for the viewport (has scrollbars)
- There is an embedded video in the page, and the video has already been started (same problems occur whether html5 or flash)

If you look at the page here: http://bit.ly/123NW1C, what seems to be happening is that under the above conditions only, the lightbox is not moving to fit the viewport as it should. This makes parts of it display twice and parts of it not display at all. Web inspector says the divs are positioned correctly, but 'as seen' they are not.

I'm currently stumped on this. The wmode fix didn't help, nor did anything else I found online. Any ideas on what this is likely to be? A bug in chrome? Or something about the way this lightbox interacts with an embedded video.

Comment: I tested your page with : Internet Explorer 9 : bug - forces Quirks mode display (and does not display). Firefox: bug, no display of the video nor the thumbnail scroller. Chrome is actually the only one that seems to work (although, yes, when I make the window small, I can reproduce your bug). Anyway, you might be under development, but the page isn't working anywhere, so please provide a working URL where we can reproduce the proof of concept.

Comment: Hi barakadam, thanks a lot for checking the site. I had forgotten to add wmode=opaque to the youtube embed query string, which fixes the 'video displaying on top of lightbox' problem on the test page. I have done this now, which makes the lightbox display properly in IE9 and firefox. However I think the chrome issue is unrelated.